# Change content on click and hover in react semantic ui popup element

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am using Popup component react-semantic-ui which triggers a pop-up on hover/click. I want to change the content based on if the triggered element was clicked or hovered. For example: I have a set boxes in my UI. When i hover on each box it should trigger the popup element but the content should only be name, when the box is clicked the full details should come. Is there a way to do that or find out the event ?

```
<Popup
  trigger={
    <span>
      I am the trigger element 
    </span>
  }
  hoverable={false}
  content={'test}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pallavi Hegde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5126170/pallavi-hegde) in order to do this, you will need to control the state of the `Popup` yourself. Right now you are relying on the internal controlled state of the `Popup` component from semantic-ui-react.

To make this work you will need to create a `handleOnClick()` and `handleOnHover()` methods which you can use on your component. You can use those methods to trigger a state change inside your popup's parent component which will change the content inside the Popup based on the hover/click state. Passing a boolean `open` prop to the `Popup` component basically disables the state.

For a good example of how controlled components work in semantic-ui-react (which is what you want) versus what you are currently doing using the out of the box functionality, take a look at this example: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup#usage-controlled